# Proof of Extended Euclidean Algorithm?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

There exist $x$ and $y$ such that: $\gcd (a,b) = xa + yb$.

Why is this true? What's the reasoning behind it?

Comment: What did you not understand in [Wikipedia's page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm)?

Comment: The standard way to go at it is to prove that the smallest positive integer of the form $ax+by$ is the gcd of $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Rather than repeat it, I'll just link you to the proof of this presented in <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity#Proof">Wikipedia</a>.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Bezout's Identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity) says that

For any pair of positive integers $a$ and $b$, there exist $x,y\in\mathbb{Z}$
so that $ax + by = \gcd(a,b)$.

**Proof:**

Consider the set
$$
    K = \{ ax + by\ |\ x,y\in\mathbb{Z}\}\tag{1}
$$
Let $k$ be the smallest positive element of $K$.  Since $k\in K$, there are $x,y\in\mathbb{Z}$ so that
$$
k = ax + by\tag{2}
$$
Because $\mathbb{Z}$ is a [Euclidean Domain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_domain), we can write
$$
a = qk + r\text{ with }0\le r < k\tag{3}
$$
Therefore, we can write
$$
\begin{align}
r
&= a - qk\\
&= a - q(ax+by)\\
&= a(1-qx)+b(-qy)\\
&\in K\tag{4}
\end{align}
$$
Since $k$ is the smallest *positive* element in $K$, $(3)$ and $(4)$ imply that $r$ must be $0$. Thus, $a = qk$, and therefore, $k$ divides $a$. Similarly, $k$ divides $b$. Thus, $k$ is a common divisor of $a$ and $b$, and therefore, $k\le\gcd(a,b)$.

Since $\gcd(a,b)$ divides both $a$ and $b$, and $k = ax + by$, $\gcd(a,b)$ divides $k$.

Since $\gcd(a,b)$ divides $k$ and $k\le\gcd(a,b)$, we get that $k=\gcd(a,b)$. Thus, $(2)$ becomes
$$
\gcd(a,b)=ax+by\tag{5}
$$

---

Futhermore, in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/730763), the following are shown for $\gcd(a,b)=1$:

1. If $c\ge(a-1)(b-1)$, then $ax+by=c$ has a non-negative solution, that is, one in which both $x$ and $y$ are non-negative integers.
2. Suppose that $0 < c < ab$ and neither $a|c$ nor $b|c$.  Then one and only one of
   $$
   ax+by=c\tag{6}
   $$
   and
   $$
   ax+by=ab-c\tag{7}
   $$
   has a non-negative solution.

Comment: Thank You. Finally made sense :)

Answer (score 7):

To understand why "there exists numbers $x$ and $y$ such that $\gcd(a,b)=xa+yb$" you should understand the Euclidean Algorithm:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm

**Euclidean Algorithm:**

Let's see what it's all about.

Given two numbers $a,b$ either $b$ divides $a$, denoted $b|a$, in which case $a=bq$ for $q\in \mathbb{Z}$; or $b$ does not divide $a$. If $b$ does not divide $a$, then there exists unique numbers $r$ and $q$ such that $a=bq+r$ with $0\le r\lt b$ (this includes the case when $b|a$, i.e. $r=0$). This is one of the first theorems addressed in most number theory texts and is key to the Euclidean Algorithm. We do this repeatedly and result with the following:

$a=bq_1+r_1$ where $0\lt r_1\lt  b$
$b=r_1q_2+r_2$ where $0\lt r_2\lt r_1$
$\vdots$ 
$r_{n-2}=r_{n-1}q_{n}+r_{n}$ where $0\lt r_{n-1}\lt r_n$ 
$r_{n-1}=r_nq_{n+1}$

This terminates when $r_{n+1}=0$, which must occur  since each number  $r_i$ decreases by atleast $1$ (termination at $r_n=0$ is formally proven by induction).

The claim is that $r_n=\gcd(a,b)$. Following the algorithm from the top down, we can see that the greatest common divisor of $a$ and $b$ is identical with the greatest common divisor of $b$ and $r_1$:

$\gcd(a,b)=\gcd(b,r_1)=\gcd(r_1,r_2)=\dots =\gcd(r_{n-1},r_n)=r_n$ (The last equality follows from the last line in Euclid's Algorithm)

**Result:**

Now that we have established $r_n=gcd(a,b)$ and Euclid's Algorithm, all we need to do is rewrite $r_n$ in terms of the previous $r_i's$. Solving the second to last line of the algorithm for $r_n$, we have $r_n=r_{n-2}-r_{n-1}q_{n}$ and substituting for $r_{n-1}$ from the previous line,  we obtain $r_n=r_{n-2}-(r_{n-3}-r_{n-2}q_{n-1})q_n$. Rearranging the terms, we get $r_n=r_{n-2}m+r_{n-3}n$ where $m=1+q_{n-1}q_n$ and $n=q_n$. This process is repeated until we have $r_n=ax+by$  where $x$ and $y$ are integers. This reasoning leads us to conclude that $\gcd(a,b)=ax+by$.

**Example:**

Using the Euclideaan Algorithm let's compute the $\gcd(68,20)=4$:

$68=20*3+8$
$20=8*2+4$
$8=4*2$

Using the procedures discussed above, we have $4=20-8*2$ and $8=68-20*3$. A little rearranging and sustitution gives us $4=20-(68-20*3)2$ which yields $4=20*7-68*2$.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 5):

The actual theorem is that

> if $a$ and $b$ are integers, and at least one of them is non-zero, then there exist integers $x$ and $y$ such that $ax+by=\gcd(a,b)$; moreover, $\gcd(a,b)$ is the smallest positive integer that can be written in this form.

This result is sometimes called Bézout’s lemma. It should not be confused with the [extended Euclidean algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm), which is an algorithm that simultaneously computes $\gcd(a,b)$ **and** a pair of integers $x$ and $y$ such that $ax+by=\gcd(a,b)$. It is entirely possible to prove Bézout’s lemma without any reference to the Euclidean algorithm; such a proof can be found [here](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_Lemma#Proof_2). (Note that they write $a\backslash b$ instead of $a\mid b$ for *a divides b*.) However, this argument merely proves the existence of such $x$ and $y$; the extended Euclidean algorithm gives an efficient mechanism for finding such a pair. The Wikipedia article on it (to which I already linked) gives a concise but complete description of the algorithm and proof of its correctness.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint** $\ $ The set $\rm\:S\:$ of integers of the form $\rm\:x\:a + y\:b,\ x,y\in \mathbb Z\:$ is closed under subtraction so, by the Lemma below, every $\rm\:n\in S\:$ is divisible by the least positive $\rm\:d\in S.\:$ Thus $\rm\:a,b\in S\:$ $\Rightarrow$ $\rm\:d\:|\:a,b,\:$ i.e. $\rm\:d\:$ is a common divisor of $\rm\:a,b,\:$ necessarily greatest, by $\rm\:c\:|\:a,b\:$ $\Rightarrow$ $\rm\:c\:|\: \hat x\:a+\hat y\:b = d\:$ $\Rightarrow$ $\rm\:c\le d.$

This *linear* representation of the the gcd is known as the *Bezout identity* for the gcd. It need not hold true in all domains where gcds exist, e.g. in the domain $\rm\:D = \mathbb Q[x,y]\:$ of polynomials in $\rm\:x,y\:$ with rational coefficients we have $\rm\:gcd(x,y) = 1\:$ but there are no $\rm\:f(x,y),\: g(x,y)\in D\:$ such that $\rm\:x\:f(x,y) + y\:g(x,y) = 1;\:$ indeed, if so, then evaluating at $\rm\:x = 0 = y\:$ yields $\:0 = 1.$

The fundamental lemma below, interpreted procedurally, yields Euclid's classical algorithm to compute the gcd using repeated subtraction. For a simple approach to the extended gcd algorithm see my [post here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/85841/242)

**Lemma** $\ \ $ If a nonempty set of positive integers $\rm\: S\:$ satisfies $\rm\ n > m\ \in\ S \ \Rightarrow\ \: n-m\ \in\ S$ 
 then every element of $\rm\:S\:$ is a multiple of the least element $\rm\:m_{\:1} \in S\:.$

**Proof** $\ \: $ If not there is a least nonmultiple $\rm\:n\in S\:,$ contra  $\rm\:n-m_{\:1} \in S\:$ is a nonmultiple of $\rm\:m_{\:1}.$

Answer (score 0):

Given that you know the phrase "extended Euclidean algorithm", the easiest proof that such an $x$ and $y$ exist is precisely because the extended Euclidean algorithm computes them.