# Use induction to prove $\gcd(m, n) = am + bn$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, induction

[image]

I tried to prove it with linear combination.

Also other information,

- $h*\gcd(m, n)=h*am+h*bn$
- At each iteration $i$, $y_i=x_iq+r$
- Last iteration $t$, so $x_t=\gcd(m, n)$.

Base case: Iteration t. $x_t=h_t*\gcd(m, n)=h_t*am+h_t*bn$. Last iteration, $x_t=\gcd(m, n)$, so $h_t = 1$. Hence, $\gcd(m, n)=am+bn$

> I don't know how to prove that m, n are positive integers and a, b are integer.

Assume iteration k, $x_k=h_k*\gcd(m, n)=h_k*am+h_k*bn$, for some integer h, $x_k$ is a multiple of gcd.

We need to prove $x_{k+1}=h_{k+1}*\gcd(m, n)=h_{k+1}*am+h_{k+1}*bn$.

> I don't know is that correct, if it is wrong, please tell me

Also, I don't know is this prove correct.

Comment: This is called Bezout's theorem, you can look it up.

Comment: What _exactly_ is the statement your are proving with induction. That is, you're proving some statement of the form $\forall k \in {\mathbb N}. P(k)$ by using induction; what _exactly_ is $P(k)$ in your case?

Comment: My $P(k)=x_k=h_k*gcd(m, n)=h_k*am+h_k*bn$. $x_k$ is the $y_k=x_kq+r$ in iteration in Euclidian algorithm.

Comment: I did say _exactly_ for a reason. What is $h_k$? What are $a, b$? Where are the quantifiers?

Comment: Oh sorry, $h_k$ is just some integer that $x_k=gcd\times h_k$ so $x_k$ is some multiple of $gcd$. From the question, a, b are some integers and m, n are positive integers. What do you mean by "quantifiers"? sorry

Comment: Are you allowed to use the well-ordering principle instead? There is a pretty direct proof using it, and the WOP is equivalent to the principle of induction.

Comment: No, $a$ and $b$ are not some integers, at least, they are not _fixed_ integers. They appear quantified (with $\exists$) in $P(k)$! Once you write down really _exactly_ what it is you're trying to prove, you'll see that the base case is totally trivial.

Comment: @Magdiragdag, I know how to do it now, thanks for directing me

Comment: @Favst, we didn't learn about that, so we can't write that, but thanks for helping

Comment: The inductive step is the same as [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/717785/242) except use mod (remainder) vs. subtraction as the method of descent to a smaller element. i.e. $\,a\Bbb Z+b\Bbb Z = \color{#0a0}{(a\!-\!qb)\Bbb Z+b\Bbb Z} = \gcd(a\!-\!qb,b)\Bbb Z = \gcd(a,b)\Bbb Z\,$ where $\,\color{#0a0}{a\!-\!qb} = a\bmod b\,$ is the remainder left by $\,a\div b.\ $ See the other dupes for more conceptual ways to do the induction (Euclidean descent) using a *fundamental* lemma about sets of integers closed under subtraction (or closed under mod or remainder).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest is to prove the basis of the *extended euclidean algorithm*: at each step of the euclidean algorithm, the remainder is a linear combination of $m$ and $n$.

Let's fix some notations: we have a sequence of euclidean divisions
\begin{alignat}{2}
m&=q_1n&&+r_1 \\
n&=q_2 r_1 &&+r_2 \\
\vdots&&&\phantom{+}\!\!\vdots \\
r_{i-1}&=q_{i+1}r_i&&+r_{i+1}\\
\vdots&&&\phantom{+}\!\!\vdots \\
\end{alignat}
and we rewrite the $(i+1)$th step as
$$r_{i+1}=r_{i-1}-q_{i+1}r_i,\tag{1}$$
so that we can make an induction of order $2$:

- *Initialisation*: conventionally, $r_{-1}=m,\: r_0=n$, and we can write
  $$r_{-1}=1\cdot m+0\cdot n,\qquad r_0=0\cdot m+1\cdot n.$$
- *Inductive step*: if we suppose $r_{i-1}=a_{i-1}m+b_{i-1}n,\quad r_i=a_i m+b_in$, and using $(1)$, we deduce instantly that
  $$r_{i+1}=(a_{i-1}-q_{i+1}a_i)m+(b_{i-1}-q_{i+1}b_i)n.$$

Answer (score 0):

So we need to prove $ h_{k+1} * $ gcd $ (m,n) = h_{k+1} * am + h_{k+1} * bn $

Actually this is [Bezout's Identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity). It states $ax+by=$gcd$(a,b)$. So are you in a good position to complete the proof OP?

Edit: Just as Magdiragdag wrote in comments:

"Actually a and b are just random integers. Once write down really exactly what you are trying to prove and you'll see that the base case is totally trivial"

Comment: The help that I need is not this, I need help proving that for any positive integer m,n, there exists integer a, b. I need help proving base case.

Comment: "Actually a and b are just random integers. Once write down really exactly what you are trying to prove and you'll see that the base case is totally trivial"

Answer (score 0):

Let $k = \gcd(m,n)$. This implies that $m=kc$ and $n=kd$ for some integers $c$ and $d$, such that $\gcd(c,d)=1$.
Now, it is only necessary to prove that two integers exist such that $ac+bd=1$, as one can then multiply both sides by $k$ to solve the original problem.

$$ac+bd=1 \implies \frac {ac}{d}+b=\frac {1}{d} \implies ac \equiv 1 \pmod d$$

Further equivalent to proving that some $a$ exists such that, for at least one value of $n$,

$$ac=nd+1$$

Edit: my bad, I didn't notice the request for this to be in induction.