# Prove that $\gcd(k,n) = 1$ if and only if $ \exists m,d \in \mathbb{Z}: mk+nd=1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, gcd-and-lcm

I need to understand why $\gcd(k,n) = 1 \Leftrightarrow \exists m,d \in \mathbb{Z}: mk+nd=1 $. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Consider the second equation, rewrite it $mk = nk+1$, where 1 - is remainder.

Comment: Do you know about Bézout's theorem ?? : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity

Comment: Do you know about the _extended_ euclidean algorithm? It proves the $\Rightarrow$ direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Bezout's Identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity) is proven in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/124991).

---

For any pair of positive integers $a$ and $b$, there exist $x,y\in\mathbb{Z}$
so that $ax + by = \gcd(a,b)$.

**Proof:**

Consider the set
$$
    K = \{ ax + by\ |\ x,y\in\mathbb{Z}\}\tag{1}
$$
Let $k$ be the smallest positive element of $K$.  Since $k\in K$, there are $x,y\in\mathbb{Z}$ so that
$$
k = ax + by\tag{2}
$$
Because $\mathbb{Z}$ is a [Euclidean Domain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_domain), we can write
$$
a = qk + r\text{ with }0\le r < k\tag{3}
$$
Therefore, we can write
$$
\begin{align}
r
&= a - qk\\
&= a - q(ax+by)\\
&= a(1-qx)+b(-qy)\\
&\in K\tag{4}
\end{align}
$$
Since $k$ is the smallest *positive* element in $K$, $(3)$ and $(4)$ imply that $r$ must be $0$. Thus, $a = qk$, and therefore, $k$ divides $a$. Similarly, $k$ divides $b$. Thus, $k$ is a common divisor of $a$ and $b$, and therefore, $k\le\gcd(a,b)$.

Since $\gcd(a,b)$ divides both $a$ and $b$, and $k = ax + by$, $\gcd(a,b)\mid k$.

Since $\gcd(a,b)\mid k$ and $k\le\gcd(a,b)$, we get that $\frac k{\gcd(a,b)}\le1$ is a positive integer. Therefore, $\frac k{\gcd(a,b)}=1$; that is, $k=\gcd(a,b)$. Thus, $(2)$ becomes
$$
\gcd(a,b)=ax+by\tag{5}
$$

Comment: Can I also ask you why "$k$ is a common divisor of $a$ and $b$" $\Rightarrow$ "$k$ divides $\gcd(a,b)$" is true?

Comment: @Jxt921: the proof of that turns out to be longer than the small amount that needs to be added to the proof by using $k\le\gcd(a,b)$, so I changed the proof to use that.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: The gcd of $k$ and $n$ is the least positive value of $kx+ny$ where $x,y$ range all over the integers.

Comment: This follows from [Bézout's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity).