# Prove that $\frac ac$ and $\frac bc$ are perfect squares

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification

$a, b, m$ are integers, such that $ab=m^2$
Prove that $a\over b$ and $b\over c$ are perfect squares, where $c$ is the GCF of $a$ and $b$.

I'm fairly new to mathematics and had never attempted to prove anything before. However, I did give this one a try and I'm hoping to receive constructive criticism, as well as other solutions to the problem(or, the *correct* solution, if mine is incorrect).

My solution goes as follows:

$ab=m^2=m(m)$

$ab$ can be represented as $m(m)$

Hence, $gcf(a,b) = c = gcf(m,m) = m$
Therefore, $\frac ac = \frac bc = \frac mm = 1$
$1$ can be represented as $1(1)$ and is a perfect square.
I apologize if the formulation of my proposed proof is incorrect or difficult to understand. I'm still learning.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: The alleged identity $\operatorname{gcf}(a,b)=\operatorname{gcf}(m,m)$ is simply not true, and in fact you should see by yourself that it doesn't quite make sense, since you end up concluding that $a=b=c=m$, while supposedly the exercise you are doing exists in non-trivial cases.

Comment: You could try a prime factorisation of $a$ and $b$

Comment: You should first try a few examples. $12\cdot 75=30^2$ but the gcd of 12,75 is clearly not $30$.

Comment: @DavidPeterson and $\frac {12}{30}\ne \frac {75}{30} \ne \frac {30}{30}=1$.  And if $\frac {a}{c} = \frac bc = \frac mm$ *were* true that would mean $a = b = m= c$.  That would mean whenever you have $ab = m^2$ that $a = b = m$.  FOr example if $4*9 = 36$ then $4=9=6$ which is obviously wrong.

Comment: If $a*b = c*d$ that doesn't mean $\gcd(a,b) = \gcd(c,d)$.    It's easy to find counter examples $1*36 = 2*18=3*12=4*9=6*6$ but $\gcd(1,36) =1$ and $\gcd(2,18)=2$ and $\gcd(3,12)=3$ and $\gcd(4,9) = 1$ and $\gcd(6,6) = 6$.

Comment: Please do not delete questions with good answers. Others have devoted effort to answer your question; deleting the question is disrespectful of their effort and prevents others from benefiting from your question and its answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prime factorization requires a fair bit of background. Here is an answer that does not use prime factorization. This answer uses [Bezout's Identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity) in the proof of the Lemma below. An elementary proof of Bezout's Identity is given in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/124991/13854).

---

> **Lemma:** If $(a,b)=1$, then $\left(a^2,b^2\right)=1$.

**Proof:** Bezout's Identity says that there are $x,y\in\mathbb{Z}$ so that $ax+by=1$. Cube and collect to get
$$
a^2\left(ax^3+3x^2by\right)+b^2\left(by^3+3y^2ax\right)=1
$$

$\large\square$

---

> **Corollary $\bf{1}$:** $\left(a^2,b^2\right)=(a,b)^2$

**Proof:** Let $g=(a,b)$. Then, $\left(\frac ag,\frac bg\right)=1$ and so $\left(\frac{a^2}{g^2},\frac{b^2}{g^2}\right)=1$. Thus, $(a^2,b^2)=g^2=(a,b)^2$.

$\large\square$

---

> **Corollary $\bf{2}$:** If $a^2\mid b^2$, then $a\mid b$.

**Proof:** If $a^2\mid b^2$, then $a^2=(a^2,b^2)=(a,b)^2$. Therefore, $a=(a,b)$ which means that $a\mid b$.

$\large\square$

---

> **Corollary $\bf{3}$:** If $ab=m^2$ and $(a,b)=1$, then $a=(a,m)^2$ and $b=(b,m)^2$.

**Proof:**
$$
\begin{align}
(a,m)^2
&=\left(a^2,m^2\right)\\
&=(a^2,ab)\\[3pt]
&=a(a,b)\\[3pt]
&=a
\end{align}
$$
Similarly, $b=(b,m)^2$.

$\large\square$

---

**Answer**

Suppose that $ab=m^2$ and $(a,b)=c$. Then $\frac ac\frac bc=\frac{m^2}{c^2}$ and $\left(\frac ac,\frac bc\right)=1$. Note that if $c^2\mid m^2$, then Corollary $2$ says that $c\mid m$. Applying Corollary $3$, we get
$$
\frac ac=\left(\frac ac,\frac mc\right)^2
$$
and
$$
\frac bc=\left(\frac bc,\frac mc\right)^2
$$

Answer (score 1):

Prime factorization of $ab$ will reveal that factors are even numbered by quantity ($2, 4$ or $6$ etc). It doesn't matter how those factors comprise to make $a$ and $b$, dividing by all the factors common to both leaves either an even number of factors in both $a$ and $b$ or a $1$.

Generalizing, looking at any one factor $f$ of $ab$, say it's $f\cdot f\cdot f\cdot f\cdot f\cdot f$, and allocating any number of $f$s to either $a$ or $b$, when diving by the lowest number of $f$s in either $a$ or $b$, there always remains an even number of $f$s or a $1$ in both $a$ and $b$. This repeats itself for any other series of factors in $ab$. Hence $\frac{a}{c}$ and $\frac{b}{c}$ will always be a perfect square.